# How to pass the state and setState to other function as parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have defined the initial state object globally as shown below.

```
   //states related code
    const [newConfigState, setNewConfig] = useState({config: {}});
    //force update states
    const [newForceUpdate, setNewForceUpdate] = useState({ forceUpdate:false, popupCancelable:false});
```

Now inside the useEffect() method i'm call some function which will do some backend api calls and based on the response i need to set the state objects, i have tried as below.

```
useEffect(() => {
        checkConfigStorage(setNewConfig, newConfigState, setNewForceUpdate, newForceUpdate);
    }, []);
```

1. Is this the right way of passing down to the function inorder to set the state?

Now the code inside the `checkConfigStorage(setNewConfig, newConfigState, setNewForceUpdate, newForceUpdate)` is as below:

```
export async function checkConfigStorage(setNewConfig, newConfigState, setNewForceUpdate, newForceUpdate) {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.CONFIG)
        .then(configstr => {
            // console.log("CNG CALLED GETITEM", configstr);
            //console.log("GLOBAL CONFIG", global.config);
            let config;
            if (configstr != null) {
                config = JSON.parse(configstr);
                console.log(config);
                if (config !== null &&
                    config.data !== null &&
                    config.data !== undefined) {
                    **setNewConfig({...newConfigState, config: {config}});**
                    if (
                        global.config === undefined &&
                        newConfigState.data !== null
                    ) {
                        global.config = newConfigState.data;
                    }
                    console.log("newConfig", newConfigState);
                    let userInfoObj = {};
                    userInfoObj.userid = userid;
                    userInfoObj.sessionid = sessionid;


                    if (newConfigState.data != null && newConfigState.data.update.version_code > AppC.current_version_code) {
                        //show popup
                        **setNewForceUpdate(...newForceUpdate, {
                            forceUpdate: newConfigState.data.update.force_update,
                            popupCancelable: newConfigState.data.update.allow_cancel
                        });**
                    }
                } else {
                    global.config = backupConfig;
                    **setNewConfig(...newConfigState, {config: backupConfig});**
                    console.log("CONFIG stored in AsyncStorage seems NULL", config.data);
                    console.log("So getting it from backup and setting to state", newConfigState.data);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("HOME 1 Error", err);
            var error = {
                err: err,
                msg: "Error : HomeScreen: checkconfig"
            };
            global.config = backupConfig;
            **setNewConfig({...newConfigState, {config: backupConfig}});**
            console.log("Caught in the catch block, assigning backup config", newConfigState.data);
            // MyEventLogger.logEventAndDesc("ERROR", error);
        });
}
```

But the problem is the new values are getting assigned to state object. When i try to print the state object value in console it's showing as below, which empty object which i had initialised in the start.

```
newConfig {"config": {}}
```

Can you please help or provide some guidance on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you calling `setNewConfig` and trying to log the next state immediately within the same function? Yeah, that won't work because react state updates are asynchronous, `console.log("newConfig", newConfigState)` will OFC log the `newConfigState` of the current render cycle.

Comment: Yes, after setting the state, i'm trying to do console.log, just to verify whether it has been set or not. If its async, then immediately after setNewConfig, i'm trying to check condition  like this newConfigState.data !== null and assigning the value to other variable like this  global.config = newConfigState.data; Even this won't work then?

Comment: Affirmative. Props are immutable, therefore constant throughout a render cycle. All state updates are queued up and batch processed for the next render cycle.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestion on how to solve in scenario?@DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using an "updated" state value later within the same function you can create an object that represents the next state, pass it to the setState callback, and use *it* instead for future comparisons.

```
export async function checkConfigStorage(
  setNewConfig,
  newConfigState,
  setNewForceUpdate,
  newForceUpdate
) {
  AsyncStorage.getItem(Constants.CONFIG)
    .then(configstr => {
      // console.log("CNG CALLED GETITEM", configstr);
      //console.log("GLOBAL CONFIG", global.config);
      let config;
      if (configstr != null) {
        config = JSON.parse(configstr);
        console.log(config);
        if (
          config !== null &&
          config.data !== null &&
          config.data !== undefined
        ) {
          // save new config for further usage
          const newConfig = { ...newConfigState, config };
          // setNewConfig({...newConfigState, config: {config}});
          setNewConfig(newConfig);
          if (global.config === undefined && newConfig.data !== null) {
            global.config = newConfig.data;
          }
          console.log("newConfig", newConfig);
          let userInfoObj = {};
          userInfoObj.userid = userid;
          userInfoObj.sessionid = sessionid;

          if (
            newConfig.data != null &&
            newConfig.data.update.version_code > AppC.current_version_code
          ) {
            //show popup
            setNewForceUpdate(...newForceUpdate, {
              forceUpdate: newConfig.data.update.force_update,
              popupCancelable: newConfig.data.update.allow_cancel
            });
          }
        } else {
          global.config = backupConfig;
          const newConfig = { ...newConfigState, backupConfig };
          setNewConfig(newConfig);
          console.log("CONFIG stored in AsyncStorage seems NULL", config.data);
          console.log(
            "So getting it from backup and setting to state",
            newConfig.data
          );
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("HOME 1 Error", err);
      var error = {
        err: err,
        msg: "Error : HomeScreen: checkconfig"
      };
      global.config = backupConfig;
      const newConfig = { ...newConfigState, backupConfig };
      setNewConfig(newConfig);
      console.log(
        "Caught in the catch block, assigning backup config",
        newConfig.data
      );
      // MyEventLogger.logEventAndDesc("ERROR", error);
    });
}
```

**An Alternative**

You can also break this logic up a bit, keeping everything *up to* the first state update call in each logic branch of `checkConfigStorage`, and simply update that state and return. In the component, apply more effect hooks that have those state values *as* dependencies to then execute the logic *after* that first update. Essentially use effect hooks to "chain" dependent state updates. I.E. `newConfigState` updated, run effect hook to check `newConfig.data.update.version_code > AppC.current_version_code` and invoke `setNewForceUpdate`, and so on.

Comment: sure, i will give try as you suggested and update back. Thank you

Comment: In the Alternative approach, you meant to say, separate the state initialise and usage of the initialised state object? right?

Comment: @coders More or less, yes, so basically up to `setNewConfig({...newConfigState, config: {config}})`, then handle that state update in an effect hook back in the component.